# How to monitor thread count for apps in Hawkular metrics in Grafana?

Tags: openshift, grafana, metrics, grafana-api, hawkular

I'm working on creating a dashboard where I can monitor the thread count for apps which are present in hawkular-metrics from openshift. (The datasource is already configured).

I do have a json file for creating dashbboard for memory usage for all the pods in our openshift project. But how do I modify it to display thread count for the pods in hawkular metrics. Currently it is displaying Average, Min and Max memory etc for all the apps in out openshift project.

The descriptor name used for memory usage in tags inside the json file is **memory/usage**.
What would be the descriptor name for thread count? And are there any modifications that I should do. Does Hawkular actually export thread count related metrics?

Here's the json file for memory usage:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "title": "Openshift Metrics",
    "tags": [],
    "style": "dark",
    "timezone": "browser",
    "editable": true,
    "hideControls": false,
    "sharedCrosshair": false,
    "rows": [
      {
        "collapse": false,
        "editable": true,
        "height": "322px",
        "panels": [
          {
            "content": "<center><p style='font-size: 40pt'>$app</p></center>",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "id": 23,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mode": "html",
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "style": {
              "font-size": "36pt"
            },
            "title": "",
            "type": "text"
          },
          {
            "aliasColors": {},
            "bars": false,
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "fill": 1,
            "grid": {
              "threshold1": null,
              "threshold1Color": "rgba(216, 200, 27, 0.27)",
              "threshold2": null,
              "threshold2Color": "rgba(234, 112, 112, 0.22)"
            },
            "id": 9,
            "isNew": true,
            "legend": {
              "avg": false,
              "current": false,
              "max": false,
              "min": false,
              "show": true,
              "total": false,
              "values": false
            },
            "lines": true,
            "linewidth": 2,
            "links": [],
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "percentage": false,
            "pointradius": 5,
            "points": false,
            "renderer": "flot",
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "seriesOverrides": [],
            "span": 6,
            "stack": false,
            "steppedLine": false,
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "none",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "avg",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "timeFrom": null,
            "timeShift": null,
            "title": "Memory usage",
            "tooltip": {
              "msResolution": true,
              "shared": true,
              "sort": 0,
              "value_type": "cumulative"
            },
            "type": "graph",
            "xaxis": {
              "show": true
            },
            "yaxes": [
              {
                "format": "bytes",
                "label": null,
                "logBase": 1,
                "max": null,
                "min": 0,
                "show": true
              },
              {
                "format": "short",
                "label": null,
                "logBase": 1,
                "max": null,
                "min": null,
                "show": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 12,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "sum",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "live",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Live, all pods",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 15,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "avg",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "live",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Live per pod",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 10,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "sum",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "avg",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Average, all pods",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 13,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "avg",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "avg",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Average per pod",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 11,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "sum",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "max",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Max, all pods",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 14,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "avg",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "max",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Max per pod",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          }
        ],
        "repeat": "app",
        "scopedVars": {
          "app": {
            "text": "aloha",
            "value": "aloha",
            "selected": true
          }
        },
        "title": "New row"
      }
    ],
    "time": {
      "from": "now-30m",
      "to": "now"
    },
    "timepicker": {
      "refresh_intervals": [
        "5s",
        "10s",
        "30s",
        "1m",
        "5m",
        "15m",
        "30m",
        "1h",
        "2h",
        "1d"
      ],
      "time_options": [
        "5m",
        "15m",
        "1h",
        "6h",
        "12h",
        "24h",
        "2d",
        "7d",
        "30d"
      ]
    },
    "templating": {
      "list": [
        {
          "current": {},
          "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
          "hide": 0,
          "includeAll": true,
          "label": "Application",
          "multi": true,
          "name": "app",
          "options": [],
          "query": "tags/container_name:*",
          "refresh": 1,
          "regex": "",
          "type": "query"
        }
      ]
    },
    "annotations": {
      "list": []
    },
    "schemaVersion": 12,
    "version": 32,
    "links": [],
    "gnetId": null
}
```

Please provide any suggestions that would be helpful.
Is there any documentation that I can look at for the list of metrics that hawkular provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any thread count metric in openshift w/ hawkular.

It's using heapster under the hood, see the metrics here: https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster/blob/master/docs/storage-schema.md#metrics.

But I'm not 100% sure if all of them are reported into hawkular.